# DLL External Function Declarations in C#

Tags: c#, dll

I am trying to access the `GetProcAddress` function in the kernel32.dll from my C# .NET 2.0 application.  The MSDN sites shows its C prototype as

```
FARPROC WINAPI GetProcAddress(
  __in  HMODULE hModule,
  __in  LPCSTR lpProcName
);
```

How do I convert this to C#?  I think I've got most of it:

```
private static extern delegate GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string lpProcName);
```

However, I think use of the `delegate` keyword is wrong.  What should I change, so that I can access this function from my application?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PInvoke.Net has a good sample for this API

```
internal static class UnsafeNativeMethods {
   [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling=true, SetLastError=true)]
   internal static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName );
}

internal delegate int DllRegisterServerInvoker();

// code snippet in a method somewhere, error checking omitted
IntPtr fptr = UnsafeNativeMethods.GetProcAddress( hModule, "DllRegisterServer" );
DllRegisterServerInvoker drs = (DllRegisterServerInvoker) Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer( fptr, typeof(DllRegisterServerInvoker) );
drs(); // call via a function pointer
```

Article Link

- http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetProcAddress.html